# Java SWT: Does exists a Calendar Widget with multiple dates selection?

Tags: java, calendar, widget, swt, datetimepicker

I need to select multiple dates on a Calendar style widget.

I only know DateTime widget, which with SWT.CALENDAR style display a calendar like this:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.CALENDAR);
```

[image]

The problem is that with this official widget I don't know if it's possible to select multiple dates. If not, does exists a widget which is able to do it?

The objective is being able to select multiple dates and that the calendar widgets returns an array with all the selected dates.

Comment: [Eclipse Nebula](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/) has several date controls some of which do multiple selection.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, but, I whould prefeer to use a widget without adding a full library.

Comment: @NullPointerException Then the answer is no.